KDE (automatic?) upscaling on a high resolution screen
Coming from Gnome > Unity > KDE.
I took the opportunity of the upgrade to 24.04 to try KDE. And I'm not disappointed!
There's just one thing that bothers me:
Having a screen resolution of 3800x2200 pixels

With Gnome/Unity, everything was tiny and I just had to switch to the lower resolution 2500x1400 for everything to appear homogeneous.

KDE on the other hand, in 3800x2200, is immediately at the right size. There must be "upscaling" somewhere (I didn't find anything in the settings).


This could be good, but some applications are not "upscaled"

Firefox for example requires additional setup - it's still okay
iBus Preferences is tiny
and now Wine (see screenshot) is just as tiny!

The best would be to not have upscaling (like Gnome); I would lower the resolution to 2500x1400 and everything would be perfect. (Currently, lowering the resolution makes KDE bigger, then wine... look normal, this is not a solution).
Is this possible?

Edit
Switched to Wayland (was X11) and everything is back to normal (no more upscaling). Maybe a bad setting in X11 was the culprit?

Edit2
Had to go back to X11 (there were issues using Wayland).
The issue persists then: at a high screen resolution most applications seem automatically upscaled using KDE, while others are not (like Firefox, iBus prefs, ...). Pretty annoying.

Before Edits:


While exploring Display Managers, I first noticed that upscaling

happens with sddm
but doesn't happen with lightdm

Then the command xdpyinfo | grep dot guided me to analyze the Xorg log.
There I found that Nvidia uses UseEdidDpi to determine the "best" DPI for my screen.
So by disabling this function in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-my-dpi.conf (new file)
Section "Device"
  Identifier "NVIDIA Card"
  Driver "nvidia"
  Option "UseEdidDpi" "FALSE"
  Option "DPI" "109 x 108"
EndSection

the window sizes became consistent and I was finally able to switch to a lower screen resolution (and force the DPI that suits me).
Note that lightdm redefines the DPI somewhere and overrides the Nvidia DPI.
And by the way, https://www.sven.de/dpi/ is nice to get a good DPI value
